# Where can I find historical business address data for specific types of businesses?

Tags: geospatial, business, historical, address

I am interested in compiling a database with the address of every operating racetrack casino establishment in the USA, for each year from 1998 to present.

This might sound like a difficult task. However, there are only 49 racetrack casinos in America at present, and they only operate in 14 states. Moreover, the [industry lobby produce a report](https://www.americangaming.org/sites/default/files/2016%20State%20of%20the%20States_FINAL.pdf#page=8) which states the number of racetrack casinos in each state for each year.

For example, from the current report, as of May 2016 the following racetrack casinos were open:

```
Delaware      3
Florida       8
Indiana       2
Iowa          2
Louisiana     4
Maine         1
Maryland      1
Massachusetts 1
New Mexico    5
New York      9
Ohio          7
Oklahoma      2
Pennsylvania  6
West Virginia 4
```

From quickly searching yellowpages.com it is pretty easy to find current racetrack casinos. For example, the four in West Virginia are:

1. Wheeling Island Hotel-Casino-Racetrack.
   1 S Stone St, Wheeling, WV 26003.
   (877) 946-4373
2. Mountaineer Casino, Racetrack & Resort.
   1420 Mountaineer CirNew Cumberland, WV 26047.
   (304) 387-8000
3. Mountaineer Casino Racetrack & Resort.
   RR 2 Chester, WV 26034.
   (800) 804-0468
4. Mountaineer Casino Racetrack.
   1000 Washington St, Newell, WV 26050.
   (304) 387-8000

I could replicate this process for the 14 states to find all 49 racetrack casinos.

My question is:

**How could I repeat this process historically? I want to do this, going back in time, for each year from 1998 to present.**

Answer (score 2):

Do you have reasons to believe that addresses of these establishments (the casino being a structure) can change?

Anyway, my best bet is to look for their EIN (Employer Identification Number) with the IRS and go over the forms they submitted through the years. For the Wheeling Island Hotel-Casino-Racetrack I found a SEC filing mentioning it, as part of the SENECA GAMING CORPORATION assets, but it does not provide its full address, just: "Wheeling Island Racetrack and Gaming Center, located in Wheeling, West Virginia" > https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1296785/000110465908078660/a08-31100_110k.htm

Comment: That is a great idea in looking at the EIN number.

Comment: Edgar is only for securities right? Most businesses aren't owned by SEC-regulated entities...